# Automatic USB syncing based on what USB is connected

Tags: windows, automation, usb

I'm looking for a program that automatically copies certain folders from my PC to my USB storage device. The program needs to:

- distinguish between different USB storage devices
- Overwrites data to USB storage device to ensure no duplicates, however doesn't format all data.

Scenario:
Dropbox which holds end of day reports for various departments, each department has their own USB. All they need to do is put the USB storage device into the designated PC wait a few minutes then pull it out with their updated files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming they are mass storage based devices bvckup has a nice device based syncing feature. Create a backup job thats triggered on insert for each device, using the "by device fingerprint" or "by volume label" option for the destination per USB device/backup directory.

[bvck2](http://www.bvckup2.com/) is free for now, and 20 dollars on release while its in beta for now, its been in development for a few years and VERY stable, even with large files.

[image]

Comment: Sounds good, is there any notification when the backup is complete?

Comment: not directly, outside the main UI. You could trigger something off with the post backup external commands if you needed a pop up of some sort.

Comment: I highly recommend Bvckup2 (http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19105/windows-8-synchronize-two-external-hard-drives-for-backup/19154#19154). It is no longer in Beta, but there is a 2 week free trial. The last beta can be downloaded at http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bvckup_2_beta.html